# Verilog 2to1 Mux bit width

Tags: verilog

I saw a 2-to-1 mux below:

wire sel,z,A,B,C;

assign z = sel ? A : {B, C};

But the output z is one bit width, why it can have two bit inputs {B,C}?
How does this mux look like after synthesis?

Comment: If `Z` is 1 bit wide and you assign 2 bits to it then the MSB will get truncated, final output will be `assign z = sel ? A : C;`

Answer (score -1):

If `Z` is 1 bit and you assign `more than one bit` to it then only `the LSB will assigned`, and `other bits will be truncated`. So it makes no sense to assign more than one bit to single bit.